# Check if File Exists on AWS S3 Using Browser JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-javascript-sdk

I recently changed the naming convention for a file in my job folders. Since I need to support both the new naming convention and the old naming convention when a user tries to download the specific file, I need to check if the new naming standard URL exists and if not, download from the old naming standard URL.

Is there a way to 'ping' a S3 URL to see if a valid file is stored at the URL? Standard AJAX calls doesn't work because of cross-domain issues.

The files I am checking for are binary files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the [headObject()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property) method in the AWS JavaScript SDK, but if the file is publicly accessible, a simple `HEAD` request (using ajax) will also do.

You can work out the cross domain issues by specifying a [CORS policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) on your bucket.

Comment: How do you check a specific file using headObject()?  With the parameters exposed, it seems you can only check for specific buckets.  Also, I noticed that I do have CORS enabled.  I just need to find a way to handle 403 responses from the server if the file doesn't exist

Comment: With `headObject()` you need to specify both the bucket and the key (the file's full path inside the bucket).

Comment: If using CORS to check for HEAD, you need to make sure to include the HEAD method in your CORS policy.  (Most default policies don't include it)  <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>